# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator - Solr Index Corrupted

Tags: solr, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have an instance of WSO2 EI 6.1.1 running on CentOS Linux 7, and out of the blue it started to spit out a `CorruptIndexException: file mismatch` error on the logs everytime I deploy an artifact of any kind. The WSO2 instance is working just fine, the deploys also get done, but something's up with the indexing. The server crashed out of memory a few days prior, so that's probably related.

This is the whole exception:

```
An error occurred while submitting the resource for indexing, path: /_system/config/repository/axis2/service-groups/CES/services/[file] 
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'registry-indexing' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:884)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer.request(EmbeddedSolrServer.java:147)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteById(SolrClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteById(SolrClient.java:717)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteById(SolrClient.java:732)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.deleteFromIndex(SolrClient.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.IndexingManager.deleteFromIndex(IndexingManager.java:164)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.submitResource(ResourceSubmitter.java:137)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.run(ResourceSubmitter.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:815)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:637)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:381)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:148)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1657)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1769)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:911)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:788)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: file mismatch, expected id=3dmwhk1nt61hefvijkvdik5y1, got=eiuu5dyvcfbb1hnk1af9iv2u3 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="/home/dev/esb/wso2ei-6.1.1/solr/data/index/_659.si")))
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeaderID(CodecUtil.java:267)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeader(CodecUtil.java:257)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:326)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:830)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:78)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:273)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1626)
    ... 12 more
    Suppressed: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum passed (1527bdd6). possibly transient resource issue, or a Lucene or JVM bug (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="/home/dev/esb/wso2ei-6.1.1/solr/data/index/_659.si")))
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:380)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.java:117)
        ... 19 more
```

I tried to search how to reset / re-index on WSO EI, but all the results were for APIM or Analytics, and the files didn't match. I also tried digging through the files, but I don't know much about WSO2 inner workings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems registry indexing has been corrupted or not happened properly. Could you follow the below steps to re-index the registry,

1. Open the registry.xml file, which is located in `<PRODUCT_HOME>/conf/`.
2. Change the `lastAccessTimeLocation` as bellow. ex: `/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime_1`
3. stop the server, back up and delete the  `<PRODUCT_HOME>/solr` directory.
4. Restart the server and wait for few minutes for re-indexing to happens

Comment: It did work, and fairly simple... Thanks a lot!